# iOS - which control is best to pick values - to be launched from UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uipickerview

I have a dialog requirement. I need a small list of static values that user must pick, and discard the dialog.

Now, this dialog must be launched from a UITableView - upon selection of specific cell.
Launched from a different cell, and the content of this dialog will differ - the static values will be different. The list is not bigger and unlikely to change, so better be static.

I started with modal view - used presentModalViewController with a UITableViewController parameter. This brought up entire table view - something which I don't want. I just need small portion of my screen to be obscured by this dialog - just like iPhone's inbuilt date picker.

I see UIPickerView can solve my issue, but can't find enough examples that suit my needs - I not only need it, but need it from a specific UITableViewCell. I also need discard button on it. I do not know if I can do it in IB, or my UITableView code would be best place to do it.

Is there any tutorial that can address my requirement? (if anything is better than picker, that's good too - just need to be smaller and modal and runnable for iOS 5,6 - both iPhone and iPad).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at iOS 6 Essentials book, here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_6_Development_Essentials

Lots of useful tips n tricks in there about UIPickerView and tableView, worth the cash if you decide to purchase it (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

I found that [UIActionSheet](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/&ei=lZmYULiEFoOurAeJ9IDgCA&usg=AFQjCNEgmE9yiZkHqT763HKBsTwOWEYUHw) is what will address my requirement.